# How to save PDF so actual size is the same as artboard size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

I created an artboard that is 1416px wide.

I need to handle the PDF to a coder, with it having the same actual size as the website.

Yet when I save it as a PDF and he gives it a 100% zoom (chooses view>actual size) it appears a lot bigger than what I intended. I checked the file dimensions and it stills says 1416px wide, also if I export it for web as a JPG and compare the two the JPG has the correct size while the PDF is bigger.

JPG Actual Size

[image]

PDF Actual Size (A lot bigger)

[image]

Why could this happen?

Comment: what's the screen resolution?

Comment: PDF is a file format linked to a phisical size, not a screen resolution. When you mention a coder... is it for a web aplication? for a downloadable file?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, then the issue is in the PDF **resolution. It should be 72 dpi.**
(The one you exported seems to be around 150 dpi).

[image: SAVE as PDF in Illustrator CS6]
Honestly, I'm no expert at all the options there. [You may check the options' meanings here (LINK)](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/pdf-options.html)

Also, like @mrserge said, if you're posting it as image, use PNG or JPG instead. Be sure to use the options Interlace or Progressive, and anti-alias.

This is for web, right? So I wonder why you're using PDF...?

Comment: Ahhh... I think I understand it now. Your coder probably prefers a PDF. Maybe he works better with it... got a workflow converting a PDF into website codes. Okay then :')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try viewing in Adobe Acrobat. They should be in sync. The default is likely that 100% in other Adobe programs = 100% in Acrobat.

Comment: Hello Shir L, thanks for your contibution. Though it would seem the asker doesn't really get to control what program others use to view their file. Also, the PDF size depends on the DPI setting of the PDF, so your second statement is false.

Answer (score -1):

1. File > SaveAs > Select the pdf format
2. Select the option 'Smallest File Size' from the dropdown menu for quality.
3. 

[image]

4. This will export your pdf in the smallest possible resolution that is your artboard size.

Comment: Hi Azif, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!